# R cut a timeseries based on the difference between two consecutive points

Tags: r, dplyr

So i have a measurement of x and y locations over time. The measurements sometimes have gaps(nothing measured).
Now I want to plot line segments only if the consecutive deltas are not larger then say 30 seconds.

How can I do this in R?

Data:

```
# A tibble: 21 x 5
           x          y           timestamp delta   cut
       <dbl>      <dbl>              <dttm> <dbl> <lgl>
 1 203.09395 348.038092 2018-01-08 17:01:41    13 FALSE
 2 180.01089 278.710786 2018-01-08 17:02:05    24 FALSE
 3 164.64089 186.764107 2018-01-08 17:02:29    24 FALSE
 4 113.96565  70.088552 2018-01-08 17:02:41    12 FALSE
 5  59.46439 103.576389 2018-01-08 17:02:53    12 FALSE
 6 354.88161   5.951221 2018-01-08 17:05:07   134  TRUE
 7 446.18112 169.600388 2018-01-08 17:05:19    12 FALSE
 8 480.14825 223.918125 2018-01-08 17:05:31    12 FALSE
 9 512.22982 222.538262 2018-01-08 17:05:43    12 FALSE
10 534.70655 234.280080 2018-01-08 17:05:55    12 FALSE
```

What I would like as a result is to create an extra factor with a new level as soon as the delta exceeds a theshold value so I can plt these segments as different.

```
# A tibble: 21 x 5
           x          y           timestamp delta   cut
       <dbl>      <dbl>              <dttm> <dbl> <lgl>
 1 203.09395 348.038092 2018-01-08 17:01:41    13 FALSE
 2 180.01089 278.710786 2018-01-08 17:02:05    24 FALSE
 3 164.64089 186.764107 2018-01-08 17:02:29    24 FALSE
 4 113.96565  70.088552 2018-01-08 17:02:41    12 FALSE
 5  59.46439 103.576389 2018-01-08 17:02:53    12 FALSE
 6 354.88161   5.951221 2018-01-08 17:05:07   134  TRUE
```

So a split here...

```
 7 446.18112 169.600388 2018-01-08 17:05:19    12 FALSE
 8 480.14825 223.918125 2018-01-08 17:05:31    12 FALSE
 9 512.22982 222.538262 2018-01-08 17:05:43    12 FALSE
10 534.70655 234.280080 2018-01-08 17:05:55    12 FALSE
```

I have looked into `cut` and `dplyr` but see no obvious solution in R?

Comment: Are the intervals (the 30 second jumps in time) to cut at random throughout the data set or are they consistent?

Comment: @paqmo they are random ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a variable `cut` already (as shown in your output), if you want a variable that gives you a new level for each cut, you could simply add:

```
new_var <- as.factor(cumsum(cut))
```

as a new variable to your data set

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the output you desire but you can use `split` and `cut`

`split(data, cut(df$timestamp, seq(min(df$timestamp), max(df$timestamp) + 31, by = 30)))`

You can modify the `cut` options `include.lowest` & `right` to defined the intervals as you want

Comment: the problem is the gaps are random ... I cannot use cut in this way